# Customizing standard three shaders

Tags: three.js, shader

I am trying to implement clipping on several already built materials.

It seems to me too difficult to re-implement everything that is already working with standard materials using `shaderMaterial`, so I am looking for a better approach.

Currently, I set a callback in three webglrenderer, function initMaterial

```
var code = chunks.join();

// CSI - Custom Shader Injection
if (material.onCustomShaderBuild)   material.onCustomShaderBuild (code, material);
// CSI - Custom Shader Injection

var program;
// Check if code has been already compiled
```

Now my callback is

```
    function myCsiFunction (code)
    {
        var myUniforms = {
        uClipPlane:   { type: "v4", value: new THREE.Vector4( 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -300.0) }, 
        clipOffset:  { type: "f", value: -40.0 },
    };

    this.uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.merge ([this.uniforms, myUniforms]);
    this.vertexShader = this.vertexShader.replace (
          "#ifdef", 
          "varying float vClip;\n uniform vec4 uClipPlane;\n #ifdef");
    this.vertexShader = this.vertexShader.replace (
          "void main() {", 
          "void main() {    vec4 pos4 = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 ); vClip = dot ( uClipPlane, pos4); ");

    this.fragmentShader = this.fragmentShader.replace (
          "#ifdef", 
          "varying float vClip;\n uniform float clipOffset;\n #ifdef");
    this.fragmentShader = this.fragmentShader.replace (
          "void main() {", 
          "void main() { if (vClip < clipOffset) discard; ");
}
```

Right now it is working, with several standard materials; but I don't like modifying three sources ...

I am very new at three, so probably I am overlooking some built in possibilities.

Could I get the same (or similar) results with the standard three unmodified?

Comment: three.js was designed to be easy-to-use, not necessarily easy-to-modify. This issue has come up several times on this board and on the three.js board. The official solution is to build your own custom `ShaderMaterial`. Any ideas you may have to improve three.js are welcome.

Comment: You may find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23717512/three-js-emissive-material-maps/23722290#23722290 useful.

Comment: @WestLangley Thanks for your comments !  However, I still think it is too hard to derive from a standard material... and that some kind of shader injector would be useful. Very interesting also the answer that you link. Thank you !