# three.js emissive material maps

Tags: three.js, maps

I'm currently experimenting a bit in three.js, and I'd like to use an emissive map. I've tried just loading a texture into the emissive property of a phong material, but it doesn't work like that, unfortunately. Here's my code:

```javascript
var params = {
    emissive: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( emissive ),
    shininess: shininess,
    map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( map ),
    normalMap: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( normalMap ),
    normalScale: new THREE.Vector2(0,-1),
    envMap: this.reflectionCube,
    combine: THREE.MixOperation,
    reflectivity: 0.05
};
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial(params);
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get the emissive map working?

Comment: `MeshPhongMaterial` does not support emissive maps.

Comment: yes, i figured. but i need emissive maps working. is there anything that does support emissive maps?

Comment: No. You can see that yourself by searching the codebase. You can, however, create your own custom `ShaderMaterial`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a material with emissive (glow) map support by extending the shaders from existing three.js materials (MeshPhong, MeshLambert, etc).

The benefit is you retain all the functionality from the standard three.js material and also add glow map support.

For the purposes of this example, I'll use the three.js Phong shader as a starting point:

- Make a "PhongGlowShader" by extending (via UniformsLib/ShaderChunk) the existing Phong shader
- Add glow map uniforms:

  ```
  "glowMap" : { type: "t", value: null },
  "glowIntensity": { type: "f", value: 1 },
  ```
- Add a glow map factor to its fragment shader:

  ```
  float glow = texture2D(glowMap, vUv).x * glowIntensity * 2.0; // optional * 2.0 and clamp
  gl_FragColor.xyz = texelColor.xyz * clamp(emissive + totalDiffuse + ambientLightColor * ambient + glow, 0.0, 2.0) + totalSpecular;
  ```
- Create a new THREE.ShaderMaterial using that shader, and pass the glow texture along with its usual uniforms

For further details, take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qr7Bb/2/.

You'll notice I made a "MeshPhongGlowMaterial" class that inherits from THREE.ShaderMaterial. That's purely optional; you can also just have a function that creates a new THREE.ShaderMaterial with the above shaders and uniforms.

The standard "emissive" property affects the entire surface of the mesh, it has nothing to do with the glow map (instead use the custom "glowIntensity" property for that).

Comment: This is not an easy problem, so congratulations on your attempt. You are using the hack `this.map = true;` in your jsfiddle example. That is a bit risky. The proper way is to set the `ShaderMaterial.defines` property, instead. Can you figure out how to do that so `defines` are set properly for all properties for which defines must be set? The goal is to make sure all other `MeshPhongMaterial` properties continue to work after you add the `glowMap` feature.

Comment: @WestLangley Thanks. The code in the fiddle (adapted from a project I'm currently working on) is intended for basic cases. I can definitely understand your point; ideally I should integrate the `glowMap` feature directly into `MeshPhongMaterial`. If I ever get around to doing (and properly testing) that, I'll be sure to send a pull request.

Comment: I've been playing around a lot with the fiddle and i think i semi-understand it now. however, I've stumbled on somewhat of a problem, i think it has to do with what WestLangley said, about the defines, would anyone be so kind and give me an explanation on how to set the `defines` ? or point me in the right direction?